# RDBMS - Normalization

Tags: rdbms, database-normalization

I've been asked a question in an online assessment test, the question goes like this..

> "In normalization, the tables are linked using?":
>
> 1. Relationships
> 2. Records
> 3. Triggers
> 4. Transactions

I haven't heard about any linking in normalization, just wanted to confirm what could be the possible answer?

Comment: i guess u failed the test:)

Comment: Well, aside from the term "normalization" (which you can likely look up), what connects tables in a relational database?  If two table contain information which relates to one another, what connects them?

Answer (score 0):

Linking refers to getting information from across multiple tables (joining). Since you only need the schema for this the only valid answer is a).